# Riverpod what to name enum types used in Providers?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Let's say I have an enum that defines the sorting mode in the UI

```dart
enum SortType {
  name,
  date,
  location,
}
```

I would like to have a riverpod Notifier that stores the current sorting mode

```dart
@riverpod
class SortType extends _$SortType {
  @override
  SortType build() {
    return SortType.date;
  }

  void switchType(SortType type) {
    state = type;
  }
}
```

This causes a rather silly naming conflict. Of course, I *could* not name the enum and the riverpod Class the same way but I would like the enum to keep the intuitive name and the notifierProvider to also have a nice autogenerated name that is `sortTypeProvider`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I'd call the enum SortingMode, and the provider CurrentSortingMode